# Show that if $f$ continuous then $f(\overline{X})\subset \overline{f(X)}$ for all $X\subset R$

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

I was able to prove that $f$ not continuous $\implies f(\overline{X})\not\subset \overline{f(X)}$ by doing this:

Being $f$ not continuous in $a$, there exists a sequence $x_n$ with $\lim x_n = a$ such that $|f(x_n)-f(a)|\ge \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$. If $X = \{x_1, \cdots, x_n, \cdots \}$ (that is, $X$ is the set of terms of $x_n$, when we say that $\lim x_n = a$, we're saying that $a$ can be made as closer to $X$ as we desire, that is, $a\in \overline{X}$. But since we can't let $f(x_n)$ be as close as we want to $f(a)$ (because $|f(x_n)-f(a)|\ge \epsilon)$, then $f(a)\notin \overline{f(X)}$, so $f$ not continuous implies that $f(\overline{X})\not\subset \overline{f(X)}$.

But I've read in my book that $$f(\overline{X})\not\subset \overline{f(X)}\implies f \mbox{ not continuous}$$

is obvious. Why?

Comment: Well, if $f(\overline{X})\not\subset \overline{f(X)}$ there exists $y$ in $f(\overline{X})$ and not in $\overline{f(X)}$. Since $y$ is in $f(\overline{X})$, there exists $x$ in $\overline{X}$ such that $y=f(x)$. Since $x$ is in $\overline{X}$ there exists $(x_n)\subset X$ such that... Can you continue?

Comment: Can you please add all of the information in the body of your question? I had to look up the tags to find that the context is metric spaces. Then the title to find that $f: \mathbb{R}\to ?$...

Comment: Supposing you know that $f$ continuous $\implies$ $f(\overline{X})\subset \overline{f(X)}$. Then you can take the contrapositive of this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\overline{f(X)}$ is a closed subset. This implies that $f^{-1}(\overline{f(X)})$ is a closed subset which contains $X$, we deduce that it contains $\bar X$ this implies that $f(\bar X)\subset \overline{f(X)}$.

Comment: Why $f^{-1}(\overline{f(X)})$ contains $X$?

Comment: Oh, that's because $f(X)\subset \overline{f(X)}$, right?

Answer (score 1):

1. The most common def'n of continuity is that $f^{-1}U$ is open in the domain whenever $U$ is open in the range. There are several equivalent def'ns.

1.What is obvious to one may be obscure to another. Suppose $f(\bar X)\not \subset \overline {f(X)}.$ Take $p \in  \bar X$ with $f(p)\not \in \overline {f(X)}.$ Then $f(p)$ has an open nbhd $U$ with$ U\cap f(X)=\emptyset.$ So  $p\in f^{-1}U$ and $$(f^{-1}U)\cap X\subset (f^{-1}U)\cap f^{-1}(f(X))=\emptyset.$$ Now if $f$ is continuous then $f^{-1}U$ is open, but then $f^{-1}U$ is a nbhd of $p$ which is disjoint from $X,$ contradicting $p\in \bar X.$ Therefore $f$ is not continuous.

2.In your proof,for functions on $\mathbb R$, the first sentence should say "there exists $(x_n)_n$ converging to $a,$ and  there exists $\epsilon >0,$ such that $|f(x_n)-f(a)|>\epsilon$ for all $ n.$" Otherwise it's good.

3.The converse also holds: If $f(\bar X)\subset \overline {f(X)}$ for all $X$ then $f$ is continuous.

For, otherwise, let $U$ be an open subset of the range with $f^{-1}U$ not open. So some $p\in f^{-1}U$ belongs to $\bar X,$ where $X$ is the complement, in the domain,  of $f^{-1}U.$ Then $f(p)\in \overline {f(X)}$ because  $f(p)\in f(\bar X)\subset \overline {f(X)}, $ so $U\cap f(X)\ne \emptyset .$.... (Because $U$ is a nbhd of $f(p)$ with $f(p)\in \overline {f(X)}$, so every nbhd of $f(p) $ intersects $f(X)....)$

But $U\cap f(X)\ne \emptyset $  is absurd by def'n of $X . $ That is, $\forall y\;(y\in X\iff y\not \in f^{-1}U\iff f(y)\not \in U).$